# Sinon spies not triggered after await - why? [Vue Unit Test]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sinon

I'm new to Vue and Vue unit testing in general, so please bear with me. :)

I need to test that two VueX actions are dispatched from the created() hook on a specific component creation. The first dispatch triggers its Sinon spy, but the second will not. No spies will function after the first await statement.

It's probably important to note that the code itself functions correctly and does what is expected. It's only the unit test that is failing.

Here is the sample code:

```
async created() {
  await this.$store.dispatch(GET_A)
  await this.$store.dispatch(GET_B)

  // Do a bunch of other things after.
}
```

This is the unit test (using Chai & Mocha):

```
// Bunch of other things happen here, like setting up localVue, etc.

describe('TestPage.vue', () => {
  let actions
  let getters
  let store
  let router

  beforeEach(() => {
    actions = {
      GET_A: sinon.stub(),
      GET_B: sinon.stub(),
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      actions,
      getters
    })

    router = new VueRouter()
  })

  it('created() should trigger the action GET_B.', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(TestPage, {
      store,
      localVue,
      router,
      attachToDocument: true
    })

    expect(actions.GET_B.called).to.be.equal(true)
  })
})
```

If I swap the order of the two dispatch methods in the created() hook, the test will pass, because GET_B is first. However, then the unit test for GET_A will fail.

I was thinking it could be something along the lines of the stubbed actions are not returning a promise, causing the test to pause at await until it times out.

I've made many attempts at finding a similar issue that others have had, and this was the closest I could get: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1735

That said from what I understand his solution at that link can't be applied here.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions as to what I can do to fix this!

Thanks.